# Stereo audio for screen recorder

Tags: audio, quicktime

I tried quicktime and monosnap to make a video tutorials, but both produce a mono audio. What should I do to make it stereo?

*nb: I'm using Steinberg CI2+ soundcard + ISK mic.*

Comment: You mean it is recording only one side of the stereo field, or it's summing a true stereo source to mono? I'm assuming you have a mono mic anyway, so what tells you it's recording in mono, & what are you expecting a stereo recording of a mono mic to sound like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, I've figured out this problem. Actually, in my soundcard there is a Mono button and when I activated it, it convert the Mono audio to Stereo. :)

Comment: Can you mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: Ups, sorry I forgot to marked it.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to record the audio separately, then merge it with the screen capture. If nothing else, you can accomplish that in iMovie.